Nucleus with the largest deformation
I am learning some nuclear physics and got interested in deformed nuclei. Which nucleus has the largest deformation, and hence the best shaped rotational spectrum?

What you mean by the "largest deformation" Are you asking which stable nucleus has the largest quadrupole moment and hence a large quadrupole splitting?  How do you compare different nuclear shapes? Is a nuclide with an octopole or hexadecapole moment "more deformed" than one with just an quadrupole moment?

@DavidBailey   Well, I actually just want a significantly deformed nucleus with very well shaped rotational spectrum

It is easy to download data from the Table of Nuclides to make a list of nuclei with the largest known quadrupole moments, but I'm not exactly sure what you mean by a "well shaped rotational spectrum"?
